# Name generation when saving InfoPath form

Tags: sharepoint-online, infopath, form-library

I have a form library with a form template. When I save the form I would like each form to save in the following format -

Name City Date To - Date From

- Eg. Joe Blogss London 02/12 - 04/12

The form submits when the user presses a button, the default Data connection has been set up with the following file name

> concat(../my:TravellerDetails/my:FullName, " ", ../my:TravelInformation/my:City, " ", substring(translate(../my:TravelInformation/my:TravelStartDate, "/-:T", ""), 7, 2), "/", substring(translate(../my:TravelInformation/my:TravelStartDate, "/-:T", ""), 5, 2),
> " ", "-", " ",
> substring(translate(../my:TravelInformation/my:TravelEndDate, "/-:T", ""), 7, 2), "/", substring(translate(../my:TravelInformation/my:TravelEndDate, "/-:T", ""), 5, 2))

This works as expected but for some reason the name field shows the forward slash as an underscore, I cannot figure out where this underscore is coming from, is there something I am missing???

I created a filename field and placed the same formula in the default value and it shows up fine in the form library
[image]

This is my submit settings

[image]

If you are wondering why I don't just use this field 'File Name' I need users to be able to click on the form and open it, this can only be done on the 'Name' field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The forward slash is an illegal character in file names and is replaced with the underscore. I would use a dash instead and that should work for you.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, I was racking my brain for too long on this!

Answer (score 1):

There are certain characters that are reserved by SharePoint and this is by design. Your concat function works great, so i can only guess that infopath got some function that replaces any reserved characters to avoid errors.

Below Microsoft states that you cannot use a slash in a file name. And any other characters.

[Information about the characters that you cannot use in site names, folder names, and file names in SharePoint](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/905231)

Comment: Thank you for the help, I appriacate it and the link was helpful